# Understanding the functor $X \times -$ (Topology: A Categorical Approach, pp. 9--10)

Tags: category-theory, functors

This is from pages 9 and 10 of *Topology: A Categorical Approach* by Bradley, Bryson and Terilla.

**Excerpt:**

> [image]

I'm trying to understand this functor and verify that it satisfies the rules for a functor as given by the excerpt below.

> [image]

**Verification:**

(i) An object $Y$ in $\mathsf{Set}$ gets sent to the object $X \times Y$ in $\mathsf{Set}$.

(ii) A morphism $f \colon Y \to Z$ in $\mathsf{Set}$ gets sent to the morphism $\text{id} \times f \colon X \times Y \to X \times Z$ in $\mathsf{Set}$.

(iii) If $g \colon A \to B$ and $h \colon B \to C$ are morphisms in $\mathsf{Set}$, then their composition is $hg \colon A \to C$. Applying the functor to $hg$ we get $\text{id} \times hg \colon X \times A \to X \times C$. I need to show that this is equal to the composition of the morphisms $\text{id} \times g \colon X \times A \to X \times B$ and $\text{id} \times h \colon X \times B \to X \times C$.

I am not sure how to do this. I think I'm being bamboozled by the notation. I need to show that $(\text{id} \times h) \circ (\text{id} \times g) = \text{id} \times hg$. Is there some identity that I need to use that I'm not aware of?

(iv) If we apply the functor to $\text{id}_X \colon X \to X$ we get $\text{id} \times \text{id}_X \colon X \times X \to X \times X$, which shows that $F \text{id}_X = \text{id}_{FX}$ as desired.

**Questions:**

How should I handle part (iii)?

Is this functor a specific example of a more general type of functor? I ask because the next example given in the book (shown below) looks very similar.

> [image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, there is a more general notion of this functor. Look up monoidal categories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You show that two functions are equal by showing that they take the same values at all points (formally this is called [extensional equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality)). So, evaluate each side on points and see what you get. You'll end up proving something more general called the interchange law

$$(f_1 \times f_2) \circ (g_1 \times g_2) = (f_1 \circ g_1) \times (f_2 \circ g_2)$$

which amounts to asserting that cartesian product $X \times Y$ is a functor in each variable. The same law holds for the tensor product and the proof is very similar.

It's annoyingly difficult to even write down things like this using "1-dimensional notation." The interchange law is about a million times more intuitive when written "2-dimensionally," using string diagrams, where it asserts that the following string diagram is unambiguous (see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/introduction-to-string-diagrams/) for details):

[image]